# Solving multi-objective function using Genetic Algorithm with the Optimization toolbox in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, genetic-algorithm, toolbox

I know there are several topics regarding this, but none of them answers my question.
My question is the following. If i use this multi-objective function:

```
function y = GAMultiobjectiveFunction(x)
q=x(1);
d=x(2);
y(1) = -(rev(q) - cost(q, d));  %by minimizing we will make -(profit) to be minimum,
                                %meaning that +(profit) will be the maximum
y(2) = 3*(power(q, 1.4))*((log(power(q,3)*d))/(d+10))+(rand*30);
end
```

in the optimization toolbox and I want to solve it by the genetic algorithm method, do I have to use the "gamultiobj" option? I want the parameters that **minimize** both equations. How do i know that it will look for the parameters that make those equations reach the minimum? I cannot specify it anywhere.

Thank you very much,
Jan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you want to minimize both you need the gamultobj function.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/gamultiobj.html

```
h = @(X)GAMultiobjectiveFunction(X);
[x,f,exitflag] = gamultiobj(h,2,[],[],[],[],... lb,ub,options);
```